# How can I increase the responsiveness/speed of my stepper motor?

Tags: arduino-uno, stepper-motor

I'm trying to control the positioning of a NEMA17 bipolar stepper motor by turning the knob of a potentiometer, using an EasyDriver board.  The control part is solved.  My problem is that if I quickly turn the knob to one end of its range and then back, the stepper motor lags behind by about 1/5 of a second.

All the spec sheets for the motor says I should be able to expect a lot more responsiveness (based on max RPM, acceleration, etc...). I'd like to speed up the responsiveness of the motor to shorten the lag. My code is as follows:

```
//Declare pin functions on Arduino
#define stp 2
#define dir 3  //LOW => forward, HIGH => backward
#define MS1 4
#define MS2 5
#define EN  6

//Declare variables for functions
int x;
int const potPin = A0;
long potval; // current analog read of A0 voltage 
int potrotsteps = 166; //num of stepper motor steps for 300-degree rotation
int cur_step_pos = 0; //current position in terms of stepper steps
long cmd_step_pos = 0; //step-position to command stepper motor to go to
int tomove; //num steps to move

void setup() { 
  //stepper motor setup
  pinMode(stp, OUTPUT);
  pinMode(dir, OUTPUT);
  pinMode(MS1, OUTPUT);
  pinMode(MS2, OUTPUT);
  pinMode(EN, OUTPUT);
  resetEDPins(); //Set step, direction, microstep and enable pins to default states
  Serial.begin(9600); // initialize serial communication at 9600 bits per second
  Serial.println("\n\n\n#################    setup completed     #################");
}

void loop() { 

  //map analog voltage read from pot to a step-position (0-166) of the stepper motor
  potval = analogRead(potPin);
  cmd_step_pos = potval * potrotsteps / 1023; // find where stepper motor should be in terms of step-position
  tomove = abs(cur_step_pos - cmd_step_pos);

  if (cmd_step_pos > cur_step_pos) { //if should-be position greater than current position
    digitalWrite(dir, LOW); // move forward
    CommandStepperMotor(tomove); //move forward by the diff in position
  } else { //if should-be position is lower
    digitalWrite(dir, HIGH); //move backward
    CommandStepperMotor(tomove); //move backward by diff in position
  }
  cur_step_pos = cmd_step_pos; //current position is now former should-be position

}

//GLOBAL FUNCTIONS

//Reset Easy Driver pins to default states
void resetEDPins() {
  digitalWrite(stp, LOW);
  digitalWrite(dir, LOW);  //default "forward" movement
  digitalWrite(MS1, LOW); // L-L => full steps, H-L => 1/2 step
  digitalWrite(MS2, LOW); // L-H => 1/4 steps, H-H => 1/8 step
  digitalWrite(EN, LOW); //Enable motor control
}

void CommandStepperMotor(int numsteps) {
  for (x = 0; x < numsteps; x++) {
    digitalWrite(stp, HIGH); //Trigger one step forward
    delay(1);
    digitalWrite(stp, LOW); //Pull step pin low so it can be triggered again
    delay(1);
  }
}
```

I understand that changing delay(1) to delayMicroseconds(100) in the **CommandStepperMotor** function should help, but as it turns out, anything smaller than a delay of 1 millisecond stalls the motor.  I've tried to Google other's solutions to the problem, but it seems they had no problem at all lowering the delay in sending the HIGH/LOW signals to the stepper pin to <1 ms.

Any ideas?  Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is that you want to go from a standstill to full speed instantly. That just isn't going to happen. As you have seen there is a limit to how fast you can go from stationary.

If you want to go faster you will have to *accelerate* up to that speed.

The simplest way to do that is to use a library that is designed for it, such as the popular [AccelStepper.h](https://www.airspayce.com/mikem/arduino/AccelStepper/index.html) library.